# I2C Reset Protocol Test

Tags: i2c

I am developing Slave module with I2C interface using stm32L1, in this module i want to test my I2C Reset Protocol.

How can i Perform this test to verify my i2c Reset working?

Bascilly the Reset Protocol is like:

1.The master shall provide up to nine SCL clock cycle (drive low, then high) to 
the slave

2.The master shall monitor SDA while SCL is high on each cycle.

3.If the slave releases SDA, it will be high and the master shall initiate a 
START operation

4.If SDA remains low after a full nine clock cycles the protocol reset has 
failed

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify this is correct: You have a slave device, and you are developing code on master (=stm32l1)?

Comment: @domen My slave device is stm32l1 based, i am using the hardware I2C peripheral  of stm32l1 to communicate with Master. So, i want  to check how robust is the Slave I2C. I am expecting to write some code on Master I2C and check the working of slave I2c device, especially the reset Protocol in case of some errors

Comment: So you control both. Just induce the condition, and see if it's correctly handled. You should also probably have an oscilloscope or logical analyser, to confirm signals are what you expect/assume them to be. 
If the i2c peripheral on chip does not allow you to create that condition, you might need to switch into GPIO mode, and do it manually.
What's the end product? Is it possible to test it on that?

Comment: @domen Since, my master is also STM32, then probably ,I should use GPIO I2C Mode in Master and create I2C error then try the Reset Procedure From Master to check if my slave responds correctly.